# Postman HTTPS request to custom port

Tags: https, postman

I'm trying to send a HTTPS GET request to a server on a custom port (not 443) using Postman. My issue is that the request is never done - when watching traffic to that particular IP using Wireshark there's no packets going out. I'm assuming Postman nas a problem with how the URL is specified, which is as follows: `https://example.com:9876/api/request`. Removing the port, so that the request looks like this: `https://example.com/api/request` fixes the problem with request not being done - it is sent, but not to the port I need it to be sent - default 443 port.

If I remove the https:// part from the front of the URL: `example.com:9876/api/request` the reqeust is done on the desired port, but in plain text (no TLS handshake is done).

Is there another way to specify the target port while also specifying that I want to use HTTPS in Postman?

Answer (score 2):

At the current date (September 6th 2017) this is a known bug in Postman.

More details can be seen on [github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3472)

Comment: I know because I've posted it :)

Comment: @JacekŚlimok haha I should've noticed the similarity in the name.

Comment: Looking further into it I see the port used in the bug is the same too! Good to know that it is getting dealt with.

Comment: This seems to still be broken at the end of 2020.  Postman v7.36.0